# ejs partials with express in sub directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have a page ./views/account/index.ejs that has a partial included from ./views/account/edit.ejs -- but I get an error that "path must be a string" when I call it from ./account/index.ejs

```
<%- partial('edit.ejs') %>
```

I'm using express 3.x and express-partials

If I include a partial that is at the base ./views/edit.ejs it works. How do I include a partial in a subdirectory? I tried `<%- partial('account/edit') %>` but it does not work.

Comment: i worked around this by using `<% include edit %>` -- it still has access to data.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue. I've fixed it inside the express-partials module and made a pull request - https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials/pull/19.

So just install the latest module version and you are done.